# Do we use "subdomain" terminology in order to specify that $Y$ is subset of domain $X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I have very simple question.

For simplicity, let's take into consideration a function $f(x)$ defined over domain $X$. I consider some set $Y$, that is $Y\subset X$. Can I say that "$Y$ is **subdomain** of domain $X$"?
Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not usually done. One would rather talk about the **restriction** of $f$ to $Y$. If $f:X \to Z$, this restriction is often denoted by $f\rvert_Y:Y \to Z$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In that case what is the precise terminology to use. Can I just say that $Y$ is subset of domain $X$ (instead of usig subdomain)?

Comment: @sane Sure, you can.

Comment: Ok, thank you!!